# Is there a way to increase CodeLens cache or persistence in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, codelens

In VS Code, if I swap between multiple tabs quickly, the CodeLens for references disappears and re-loads every time, which is annoying and jarring.

Is there a way to increase the cache or persistence of CodeLens annotations so that, for example, all open tabs do not reload & reflow every time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, as of VS Code 1.13 code lens persistence is not something you can control.

We are tracking [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19917) that may be related to this, and feel free to [file another feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new) if that issue does not cover what you are after

Thanks